# Classic Mac OS colors to modern RGB

Tags: color, classic-mac-os

I want to find a way to convert RGB colors used by classic Mac OS to RGB colors that are understandable to modern image editors and to web browsers.

The two palettes that are subjects of my interest are as follows:

## System 4.1 system colors

```
R      G      B
65535, 65535, 65535
64512, 62333,  1327
65535, 25738,   652
56683,  2242,  1698
62167,  2134, 34028
18147,     0, 42302
    0,     0, 54272
  577, 43860, 60159
 7969, 46995,  5169
    0, 25775,  4528
22016, 11421,  1316
37079, 29024, 14900
49152, 49152, 49152
32768, 32768, 32768
16384, 16384, 16384
    0,     0,     0
```

## System 7 icon colors

```
R      G      B
65535, 65535, 52428
65535, 52428, 39321
52428, 39321, 26214
65535, 26214, 13107
13107, 65535, 39321
    0, 48059,     0
13107, 39321, 26214
13107, 26214, 26214
39321, 65535, 65535
    0, 39321, 65535
    0,     0, 56797
13107,     0, 39321
52428, 52428, 65535
39321, 39321, 65535
26214, 26214, 52428
13107, 13107, 26214
65535, 26214, 52428
39321,     0, 26214
39321, 26214, 39321
65535, 65535, 65535
61166, 61166, 61166
56797, 56797, 56797
52428, 52428, 52428
48059, 48059, 48059
43690, 43690, 43690
34952, 34952, 34952
30583, 30583, 30583
21845, 21845, 21845
17476, 17476, 17476
 8738,  8738,  8738
 4369,  4369,  4369
    0,     0,     0
65535, 65535,     0
56797,     0,     0
```

As you can see, the color values are from 0 to 65535. What I don't understand is that how to *properly*, that is, precisely, convert them to "modern" RGB, such as, for example, `rgb(100, 149, 237)` for cornflower blue.

[I have asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76799871/to-convert-rgb16-values-to-rgb8) and there is an answer there, but:

1. As follows from the discussion there, RGB565 is not the same as RGB16, but both of them use color values from 0 to 65535, and this means I don't understand which of these two RGB variants were used by classic Mac OS, and this means I don't know whether the answer there gives accurate values if we talk about converting colors of classic Mac OS.
2. [Later I have found another answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442576/how-does-one-convert-16-bit-rgb565-to-24-bit-rgb888), and after reading it I suspect that the conversion proposed in the first answer is not really correct at all, because shifting for G must be different from shifting for R and B.

If there are vintage Mac gurus here, plese help me to not go cranky.

**Edit:** Also answered here: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27436

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have simply misunderstood those answers in terms of what RGB16 and RGB565 and so forth actually means. Therefore you're asking question that do not make any sense.

You have 16-bit RGB values from an old Mac system. As you have described, you mean that you have 16 bits for the red color, 16 bits for the green color and 16 bits for the blue color.

You have then read something about 16-bit RGB565 systems and jumped to the wrong conclusion that it has anything to do with your 16-bit values. In a RGB565 system, you have 16 bits *in total* for red, green and blue. I.e. you have 5 bits for the red color, 6 bits for the green color and 5 bits for the blue color - totalling 16 bits. This is also the reason why the conversion formula for the red and green colors are different (as you have also noted in your answer).

So your problem has nothing to do with RGB565. The solution in your case is super simple - just divide the 16-bit RGB values you have with 256.

If you're doing serious retro work, such as for example trying to make a very realistic emulation of old computers, you would go further than just dividing by 256. Modern displays are very different than retro-displays. This means that a pixel with a RGB color shown on an old CRT display doesn't really look the same as a pixel on a modern display with the corresponding RGB color. Emulators of various kinds employ various graphics filters and color palette manipulations to try and closely match the "CRT look and feel" of yesteryear.